# Trying to use standard deviation java

Tags: java, math

Hi I"m trying to use a standard deviation library from Apache Commons Math. I'm unable to import the library because I can't find the jar file after I download the zip. Am I missing something that's too obvious?

Comment: Did you extract the JAR from the zip and add it to the build path of your project?

Comment: Um...unzip the zip file to find the jar file inside? Make sure the jar file is on the build path for the compiler.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the jar in the classpath, posting the error will help us

Comment: I unzipped it. I see the src "folder" , an xml file and a few text files, no jar file..

Comment: Maybe you downloaded a bad zip that erroneously did not contain the jar file. Try another?

Comment: They have a [binary](http://apache.openmirror.de//commons/math/binaries/commons-math3-3.0-bin.zip) and a source distribution. You'll want the binaries (that includes the jar file, just had a look at it).

Comment: It's from the apache website...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the [Download Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/download_math.cgi) page and download the current binaries release. At the moment this is commons-math3-3.0-bin.zip. From your comments it is obvious that you downloaded the archive containing sources.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unzip the zip file [7zip works great for unzipping things](http://www.7-zip.org/)
2. Make sure the jar is in the build path for the compiler  [How to add Jars to your build path in eclipse](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29)
3. Profit???

Are you sure the jar is in the classpath?

[I see the jars in here, Download it from here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/math/binaries/)

Comment: Hey, I've seen this before wasn't ist - wait - yes, that's exactly what Ted wrote in his comment... (-1 for copy&paste without leaving credits...)

Comment: I can't find the jar file, i know how to add it in to the build path

Comment: in a 60 second time difference its not possible for two people to have the same thought at the same time, yet the person with the shorter comment some how finishes it first?

Comment: (hmm - just received an uncommented downvote for a simple and correct answer. Strange. Smelled like a revenge foul. I usually delete my downvoted stuff, so that would actually hit those who asked for help, they lose their valid answers)

Comment: just take into account post time in the future.

Comment: That's what *I* saw shortly after I left my comment and downvote: Ted: 4 mins ago, Bob: 3 mins ago. Ted was first. There was enough time to quickly compile a draft answer from two(!) comments (the one with *Are you sure the jar is in the classpath?* has been deleted already). Initially there was a 100% match. Otherwise I wouldn't have commented.

Answer (score -1):

Get a build+dependancy management tool and you will not have problems like this. I suggest you to go with apache buildr ([quick start](http://buildr.apache.org/quick_start.html#first-project)) and a buildr file like this:

```
repositories.remote << 'http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2'

define 'killer-app' do
  project.version = '0.1.0'
  compile.with 'org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.0'
  package :jar
end
```